# How show / hide a div with a random timing function

Tags: javascript, html, css

i search to make a glitch animated video. I use 2 videos to make the glitch. One is totally glitched and i just want to let her appear or disapear randomly with a random timing function with a range of time.

How is it possible to complete or recode this tiny piece of Javascript?

I just need to make a show/hide with random time of hide ... showed max 5s and hide between 20s and 120sec

Please have a look at the code :

```js
setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('Video1').style.display = 'none';
    }, 3000); // 10000ms = 10 seconds
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="Video1" id="Video1" name="Video1">Video1</div>
<div class="Video2" id="Video2" name="Video2">Video2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion will call the setTimeout and toggle the appearance of your div.

Video1 will show in the 5 seconds interval. Once closed, it will remain that way within 20-120 [s] interval and this will repeat indefinitely.

```js
function callTimeout(isOpen, time) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (isOpen) {
      document.getElementById('Video1').style.display = 'none';
      time = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 120) + 20) * 1000;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('Video1').style.display = '';
      time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) * 1000;
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
    callTimeout(isOpen, time);
  }, time);
}

callTimeout(true, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) * 1000)
```

```html
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div class="Video1" id="Video1" name="Video1">Video1</div>
    <div class="Video2" id="Video2" name="Video2">Video2</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen, this is a good start, video1 well disappear randomly, but dont re-appear randomly. Can you comment function times parameters ?

Comment: @Cudex it will reappear wait for 20-120 seconds as you stated. the arguments are just the intervals which you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Very good, a big thanks To you Eugen.

I have modify arguments to make it more dynamic. It was too slow to have the glitch/no glitch effect .

```js
        function callTimeout(isOpen, time) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (isOpen) {
      document.getElementById('Video1').style.display = 'none';
      time = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1) * 1000;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('Video1').style.display = '';
      time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 1000;
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
    callTimeout(isOpen, time);
  }, time);
}

callTimeout(true, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) * 1000)
```

```html
<div class="Video1" id="Video1" name="Video1">Video1</div>
<div class="Video2" id="Video2" name="Video2">Video2</div>
```